# CSS Border Meeting point

Tags: css, border

I am hoping someone can help me with a css problem...

I am using a listview to display some results, there is required to be a concept of grouping, to achieve this i am using 2 background colors alternating between groups. I am trying to add a border to these elements, but as the border-top and the border-left may be different colors, is there any way of removing the triangle where they meet?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <style type="text/css">
 p
 {
 border-top:10px solid red;
 border-left:10px solid white;
 border-bottom-style:dotted;
 border-left-style:solid;
 }
 </style>
 </head>

 <body>
 <p>2 different border styles.</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Could you show us an example of what you mean by this?

Comment: the corners meet at an angle, if the left border is red, and the top border is white, i am left with a red arrow from where the red border is meeting the white border

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
p{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    border-left:5px solid pink;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 5px green;
    box-shadow:inset 0 5px green;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/nRWux/1/

box-shaow not work in IE8 & below.

Comment: This is great, but there's still a slight amount of shadow crossing into the border at the very bottom, slightly transparent. Not a problem in most cases, but if you need to be pixel-perfect a different solution would probably be better.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution compatible with IE8+ using :before `pseudo`:

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/hXrW5/

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <style type="text/css">
 p {
     position: relative;
     border-top:10px solid red;
     border-bottom-style:dotted;
     border-left-style:none;
 }
 p:before {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     width: 10px;
     position: absolute;
     top: -10px; /* top: 0; if you want red over blue (top over left) */
     bottom: 0;
     background: blue;
 }
 </style>
 </head>

 <body>
 <p>2 different border styles.</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use box-shadow for the border-top,

In your example: http://jsfiddle.net/C7jnJ/

```
margin-top:10px;
box-shadow:0 -10px 0 10px red;
```

Instead of border-top. The margin-top is added because the shadow is displaying outside the 'p', If you would like it inside, then it would be: http://jsfiddle.net/C7jnJ/1/

```
box-shadow:inset 0px 10px 0px red;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to remove the triangle where they meet. borders are implemented that way and there is no way around.