# html+css tables - border-bottom of tr overlaps border-right of td/th

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

Here is a sample of my current code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzALe/)

The problem is, the dark gray line between the table header and body is getting cut by the margin-right of the cells. I want to have a that border between columns and a non-breaked margin between header and body table.

Here is the HTML:

```
<table id="prazo">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>month</th>
      <th> val </th>
      <th> val </th>
      <th> val </th>
      <th> val </th>
      <th> val </th>
      <th>val</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="srow">
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="srow">
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and the css:

```
#prazo {
    font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

#prazo thead tr{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #7d7d7d !important;
}



#prazo td, th {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-right: 3px solid #f6f6f6;
}

.srow td {
    background-color: #f2f2f2 !important;
}

#prazo th {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: If you reduce the border to 2px then it collapses fine. I'll have a look more into this, but for now here is a jsFiddle of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/mzALe/7/

Comment: @Martin good spot seems to take the highest width border over the lower one

Comment: Also, don't style TRs. And if you'd really like to save the 3px border-width on the right of each cell, you could always do <tr><td colspan="7" style="height:3px;background:red;"></td></tr> directly underneath your TR with THs.

Comment: @Martin thanks, it worked. It would be good to keep the 3px border instead of the 2px one. And I'm curious about this solution. By now I'll use yours :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can come up with is to either: 
increase the width of the darker border to 4px (`border-right: 4px solid #7d7d7d;`)
or
reduce the width of the other border to 2px (`border-right: 2px solid #f6f6f6;`).

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzALe/7/)

Not the best of answers, but it does give you a solid dark border and keep the lighter one between the th cells.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to give bottom border to each header cell.

Please add following style:

```
#prazo th {
    font-size: 16px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #7d7d7d !important;
}
```

Please check here for [`demo`](http://www.jsfiddle.net/mzALe/14)

Comment: As with the other answer you would lose the line between the th cells.

Comment: @Martin Does he wants border between header cells?

Comment: the question doesn't specifiy, but as they were there before hand I assumed so.

Comment: Yep, I want the border beetween th cells

Answer (score 0):

```
#prazo td, th {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-right: 3px solid #F6F6F6;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

remove following line from above css

```
border-right: 3px solid #F6F6F6;
```

Comment: You would then lose the line between the right of the th cells.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing your final style to:

```
#prazo th {
    font-size: 16px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #7d7d7d !important;
    border-right:0 !important;
}
```

and removing the bottom border higher up

Comment: Comment on @Parixit's answer threw me off, but yeah his solution produces the same style as this.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are curious here is a [good approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206455/css-border-meeting-point?answertab=votes#tab-top).

I used Martin solution :)